# Unable to prove assign clause - Frama-C

Tags: frama-c

I'm new to Frama-c and I'd like to understand what is the problem with this simple example :

```c
/*@ requires \valid(array+(0..length-1))
@ ensures \forall integer k; 0 <= k < length ==> array[k] == 0;
@ assigns array[0..length-1];
*/
void fill(int array[], int length){
    /*@ loop invariant 0 <= i <= length;
    @ loop invariant \forall integer k; 0 <= k < i ==> array[k] == 0;
    @ loop assigns i, array[0..i-1];
    @ loop variant length - i;
    */
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        array[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

In this example, Frama-c (WP + Value) won't prove the assign clause in the function contract and I can't understand why. Any help will be appreciated =)

Comment: why? Isn't it ok? I just want to fill an array of int (declared statically) with zeros... Isn't int * array[] an array of int pointers?? Anyway it doesn't do the trick :/

Comment: I don't see what you mean. Even with this signature fill(int * array, int length), the problem is still here...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem In C, arrays are passed by reference. The function is fine, and the specifications are fine. The Value plug-in does not prove the “assigns” because it does not aim to do this (it only uses “assigns” clauses as a source of information, and only for library functions without source code). I thought WP would prove it. Roo, what automatic provers do you have installed?

Comment: Since `length` is passed as `int` I would add the precondition that `length` is `≥0` or `>0` though (whichever you prefer).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: My bad, I've googled Frama-C, and _now_ I know what this question is about. That's why I commented, and not set about writing a lengthy answer. I got the impression there was more to this than I initially thought...

Comment: @PascalCuoq : adding the preconditions length >= 0 or length > 0 doesn't solve the problem (isn't it implied by the precondition \valid(array+(0..length-1))??). I have Alt-Ergo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be proven (with alt-ergo 0.95.1) if you weaken your loop assigns.

> @ loop assigns i, array[0..length-1];

The precondition `i >= 0` is also needed, because it is *not* implied by `\valid(array+(0..length-1)`. `array+(0..length-1)` is a valid set of locations with `length <= 0`, although an empty one.

The fact that your original loop assigns does not imply your precondition is a limitation of the current version of the WP plugin.

Comment: Hi Boris, thanks for your answer. I knew that I could prove it by weakening the loop assigns but I wanted to know why it doesn't work with a stronger but correct clause.

Thanks for the explanations!

Comment: If you like Boris's answer, you should mark it as accepted (the checkmark under the voting buttons).